# How to pass a required file into app use

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying this in app.js cuz code encapsulation is awesome

```
app.use('/user',require('./routes,js')(app,mongoose,passport)
```

routes.js is like

```
module.export=(app,mongoose,passport)=>{app.post('/index',(req,res,next))}
```

but a type error keeps popping

```
Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined
```

Comment: You don’t return anything from you routes function, so 2nd argument of `use` is missing.

Comment: Also you are missing an `s` in `module.exports`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return something from your `routes.js` file. You could change your `routes.js` to:

```
const express = require('express');

module.exports = (app, mongoose, passport) => {
   const router = express.Router();
   router.post('/index', (req, res, next) => {
       /* do something */
   });
   return router;
}
```

Comment: It is not another express instance, see: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router